# Alloy terminology: signature "declaration" and signature "introduces" atoms

Tags: alloy

Consider this:

```
sig A{}
```

What is that?

Answer: It is a signature *declaration*.

What does it do?

Answer: It *introduces* a set of atoms. (See page 93 of Software Abstractions)

Is *declaration* and *introduces* standard terminology in the lightweight formal modeling community?

Why isn't the terminology this:

What is it? Answer: It's a signature *definition*.

What does it do? Answer: It *creates* a set of atoms.

Or some other terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Declaration" is a standard term in programming or spec languages for introducing (-;) a variable without giving it a value. I used the term "introduces" rather than "creates" to avoid the implication that there is an immediate operational effect (since the set of atoms is determined by constraint solving).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you @Daniel Jackson!